# how to show new image from previous activity index value in android

Tags: android, image, gridview

I am working on gridview but when I use all drawable images to show in gridview. I am getting out of memory error. Its obvious. Now I am looking for workaround condition. I am taking help from android hive example. I want to show grid images in thumbnail and on click on that image I want to send the index of that to new activity. And in new activity I have new drawables array I want to set image based on index value I got from previous activity.

FullImage Activity-

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }

}
```

Here I want to assign new image in above code-

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
```

New Image array that I want to include in above code-

```
 public Integer[] nImages = {
            R.drawable.kri1, R.drawable.kri2,
            R.drawable.kri3, R.drawable.kri4,
            R.drawable.kri5, R.drawable.kri6,
            R.drawable.kri7, R.drawable.kri8,
            R.drawable.kri9
};
```

Edit-

**Gridview showing mThumbIds images to show. On click on any image I want to show full image So I am passing index to full size activity. Now I want to use that index and image from new array nImages that I am creating in this activity. So index value from previous activity and new image from full size activity to open.**

Please help me.

Comment: where u get error then

Comment: Its show change nImages to mThumbsIds

Comment: means like u want to click on gridview position of any image and in next activity that clicked image show in image view Is it u want

Comment: @BhanuSharma I think now its clear please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Get the position when you click on the GridView. Then pass that position in put extra like this:

```
intent.putExtra("imageResourceID", nImages[position]);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Get that int in fullimage activity like this:

```
int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("imageResourceID", 0);
```

Now from new array nImages pass this position in new one like
`nImages[position]` and get that image resource and set in ImageView resource.

Comment: I have image in gridview activity in mThumbIds array with name image1 and the index of this image is 2 in array. I want when i click on this image index 2 is passed to full image activity. Then in full image activity I have array name nImage I want image in that array on index 2 to be open.

Comment: this then pass this 2 in that array get image resource and set that on image view simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are sending `position` value to your full image activity, instead send Image resource ID.

For example:

```
intent.putExtra("imageResourceID", nImages[position]);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

And inside full Image activity, get the image resource Id and display it in a simple way by using `image.setImageResource()`.

Comment: mThumbsIds include all thumbnail small sized images. And nImages include full sized images. I dont want to scale small images. I want to get the postion of thumbnail image got clicked. And in full size activity use that position to set image from new array in this activity.

Comment: @JohnR have you mentioned this anywhere in your question? Please understand someone's time and effort putting to help you out!

Comment: sorry. But I've upadated question. Please help me.